# ViewModel crashing while trying to recreate without factory

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

**How to recreate `ViewModel` that was created with params injected via `Factory` after instance of activity is recreated?**

`ViewModel` has a constructor like this:

```
class MyViewModel(
        val model: MyModel,
        val repository: MyRepository
) : ViewModel()
```

I instantiate it with factory:

```
ViewModelProviders
                    .of(this, MyViewModelFactory(
                            model = MyModel()
                            repository = MyRepository()))
                    .get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

I tried to recover `ViewModel` like this, while `savedInstanceState` is not null (activity is recreated):

```
ViewModelProviders
                    .of(this)
                    .get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

This causes a crash because `no 0 arguments constructor` is present inside `MyViewModel` class.

**As, for passing factory each time:**
My problem with that is, that whatever I pass as a `MyModel` to `ViewModel`, and that comes from activity `Intent`, might change later, due to user interaction. That would mean, when recreating, the `MyModel` in the Intent is outdated to the model that is already stored in `ViewModel` and was tampered by user interaction.

Comment: Refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419236/why-a-viewmodel-factory-is-needed-in-android/54420034#54420034

Comment: Your ViewModel would be preserved (along with the data it is holding) during activity recreation. You don't have to recreate it after activity recreation, Android system would do that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the only answer is, that it cannot be done this way. If the factory was provided, it has to be provided at all time. I don't know mechanism underneath `ViewModel` recreation but these are not as smart as I hoped.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders
            .of(this, MyFactory(MyRepository()))
            .get(MyMViewModel::class.java)

    val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityCreateFoodstuffBinding>(this, R.layout.my_activity)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        val model = intent.getParcelableExtra<MyModel>("model")
        viewModel.model.set(model)
    }
```

I use one param constructor in `ViewModel` that always takes repository, but model I moved away and set it only when the activity is freshly created.

Answer (score 2):

> This causes a crash because no 0 arguments constructor is present
> inside MyViewModel class.

It'll crash, as you're not passing any factory to construct the `ViewModel`.

> How to recreate ViewModel that was created with params injected via
> Factory after instance of activity is recreated?

**AFAIK**,  you don't have to manually recreate the `ViewModel` on `savedInstanceState`. You may use `viewModel` to store data that are used in the activity.So, on recreation of the activity, the `ViewModelProvider` will not create a new instance of the `viewModel` but will give you the old instance and the data held in the `viewModel` will not be cleared.So there's no need to worry about `savedInstanceState`.

**TIP:** If you want to manage the creation of the factory and improve the recreation process. you may check [this article on ViewModel with Dagger](https://medium.com/@marco_cattaneo/android-viewmodel-and-factoryprovider-good-way-to-manage-it-with-dagger-2-d9e20a07084c)

Comment: I think `model` and `repository` may be dependent on `savedInstanceState` value but not the viewmodel.

Comment: I believe, `model` and  `repository` shouldn't be visible to `Activity` and should be accessed via `viewModel`. Why should we use `savedInstanceState` ? @ArkaPravaBasu

Comment: I believe principles of DI says the opposite. If a ViewModel is dependent on a repository and model, those should be injected into it instead of ViewModel taking up the responsibility of instantiating them.

The `savedInstanceState` flag use is implementation and use case specific. Without actually knowing what data `Model` stores and what data `Repository` needs I am not sure in which way I would use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no 0 argument constructors in `MyViewModel`. When you try to get the instance of ViewModel without providing a Factory it will look for a 0 argument constructor.

You can use this regardless of whether `savedInstanceState` is `null` or not.

```
ViewModelProviders
                    .of(this, MyViewModelFactory(
                            model,repository))
                    .get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Rather how you create `repository` and `model` changes on the basis of `savedInstanceState` value, depending on your use case or implementation.