# Android Room with a View - Java triggers error: WordViewModel has no zero argument constructor

Tags: java, android, google-codelab

I have stepped through the [Android Room with a View - Java](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#0) codelab and wound up with an error that causes the app to crash before it loads (see "fatal exception", below). Thinking perhaps I did something wrong, I copied the contents of each of the [.java solution files](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample) from github.

I tried creating overloading the WordViewModel class with another constructor that took no arguments, but that only created more issues.

```
public WordViewModel( ) {
    super(new Application());
    mRepository = new WordRepository(new Application());
    mAllWords = mRepository.getAllWords();
}
```

**Fatal Exception:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.roomwordssample, PID: 32145
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.roomwordssample/com.example.android.roomwordssample.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.android.roomwordssample.WordViewModel
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.android.roomwordssample.WordViewModel
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
    at com.example.android.roomwordssample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
 Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.android.roomwordssample.WordViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
    at com.example.android.roomwordssample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Any ideas what could be triggering this?

**Update:**
Also tried copying the app and project build.gradle files over from the solutions on github. To let it compile I had to change the `minSdkVersion` to 21 (from 20) to resolve a build error regarding vector graphics. Also changed the dependency to gradle version 4.1.0 (from 3.4.3 in the solution). Compiles, but running the app triggers the same error as above.

**Update #2**
Also tried copying over gradle-wrapper.properties (which references gradle-5.1.1-all distribution) and restoring the buid.gradle to the solution's version (which references Gradle plugin version 3.4.3). Still no dice.

**Update #3**
I downloaded the [entire solution project from GitHub](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample) and imported it into a new project in Android Studio. It compiles but generates the exact same `no zero argument constructor` error.

Comment: Either you need to have viewmodelfactory class or pass the param to viewmodel. please this link. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419236/why-a-viewmodel-factory-is-needed-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix posted on the [GitHub issues tab for this project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/issues/129) which resolved this for me:
Simply open MainActivity.java and within `onCreate`, find:

```
mWordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel.class)
```

And change it to:

```
mWordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(WordViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `viewModel` accepts zero args which mean there will be no arguments in the `viewModel` just an empty constructor
But if you wanna pass something in the `viewModel` constructor. 
There are two ways:
1-> **AndroidViewModel**: Which accepts only one type of arg and it is `applicationContext`

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {}
```

*Remember: no other value can be passed in constructor args when you are using `androidViewModel`*
2-> **ViewModelFactory**: You will be using regular `viewModel` but you are making extra `viewModelFactory` class:
here is complete implementation of `viewModelFactory`:
**ViewModel**

```
class MainViewModel(val value: Int): ViewModel() {}
```

**ViewModelFactory**:

```
  class ViewModelFactory(
       private val value: Int     
        ): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel::class.java)){
                return MainViewModel(value) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid model class")
        }
    }
```

**Your Activity**:

```
lateinit var viewModel : MainViewModel
private val viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = ViewModelFactory(10)

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)[MainViewModel::class.java]
}
```